# How to publish SharePoint Add-in project IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am working on SharePoint add-ins. I followed the followed steps from the following reference.
[Step By Step Procedure To Create A Low Trust Provider Hosted App For Office 365 And Host The AppWeb In Local IIS](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-create-a-low-trust-provider-hosted-app-for-office-365-and-host-the-appweb-in-local-iis/) to host my SharePoint add-in IIS. I have successfully followed his steps till step 39. But, I am don't know how to publish the project on IIS as I am using visual studio 2017. I am getting this screen.
[Visual Studio 2017 publish screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3oJB.png). I am not getting custom profile in the setting. I tried to create new profile but i don't know, what to fill in [Custom Profile setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySpIT.png).

Comment: in publish select the iis,ftp, etc and add the site name which you mentioned in iis and site URL. [img](https://i.imgur.com/bgiuJoC.png)

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal No, i didn't work. I am using this reference https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-create-a-low-trust-provider-hosted-app-for-office-365-and-host-the-appweb-in-local-iis/  . I have followed till step 39 and i don't know what to do in step 40